# Convert to full free format Datastructure with fixed positions

Tags: data-structures, ibm-midrange, rpgle

i'm converting a program to full free format but don't know how to replace a data structure with fixed positions. and i cant find a good example online also.

i have 2 data structures like below.
i tried

```
dcl-ds bl dim(12)
bl01 char(7);
bl02 char(7);
...
end-ds
```

and

```
 dcl-s bl char(7) dim(12);
```

this is the part that i try to convert

```
 //*************************************************************************
  // NORMAL DATA STRUCTURES                                                 *
  //*************************************************************************
 D                 DS
 D  BL                     1     84
 D                                     DIM(12)                              BARCODE LABEL
 D  BL01                   1      7
 D  BL02                   8     14
 D  BL03                  15     21
 D  BL04                  22     28
 D  BL05                  29     35
 D  BL06                  36     42
 D  BL07                  43     49
 D  BL08                  50     56
 D  BL09                  57     63
 D  BL10                  64     70
 D  BL11                  71     77
 D  BL12                  78     84
 D                 DS
 D  TL                     1     72
 D                                     DIM(12)                              TEXT LABEL
 D  TL01                   1      6
 D  TL02                   7     12
 D  TL03                  13     18
 D  TL04                  19     24
 D  TL05                  25     30
 D  TL06                  31     36
 D  TL07                  37     42
 D  TL08                  43     48
 D  TL09                  49     54
 D  TL10                  55     60
 D  TL11                  61     66
 D  TL12                  67     72
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Do not use the first option here.  Leaving answer here as is because it is good to note when an option is incorrect.

You have two options here.  You can use either `pos` or `overlay`.  `overlay` positions relative to another field while `pos` is an absolution position.

```
dcl-ds *n;
    bl char(7) dim(12);
    bl01 char(7) overlay(bl);
    bl02 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl03 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl04 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl05 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl06 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl07 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl08 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl09 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl10 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl11 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
    bl12 char(7) overlay(bl:*next);
end-ds;
```

The other option:

```
dcl-ds *n;
    bl char(7) dim(12) pos(1);
    bl01 char(7) pos(1);
    bl02 char(7) pos(8);
    bl03 char(7) pos(15);
    ...
end-ds;
```

Comment: While these are direct conversions, I'd highly recommend naming the data structure rather than leaving it unnamed via `*n`

Comment: The first option is not correct. When subfields (bl01, bl02 etc) overlays an array (bl), they also become an array. The definition for bl02 would get an error because it ties to put the bl02 array starting at position 8 of the 7-character bl array.

Comment: @Barbara Morris Thanks.  I didn't realize that.  I try to avoid using overlay in general whenever possible.  It usually only comes up when something was converted from old fixed format code with bad modern practices.  Is there a correct format that works or should I just delete that option from the answer?

Comment: @Player1st, you could add an unnamed item, say bl_info, then define all the bl01 etc to overlay bl_info instead of bl, and then define bl last, overlay(bl_info:1). Important to define the bl array last, since *next means "next after all the other things overlaying this", not "next after the previous thing I defined overlaying this".

Comment: In general, overlaying arrays can be very useful. If you had say an array INFO DIM(100), and you had fields NAME, ADDR, ID overlaying INFO, then when you sort the NAME, ADDR or ID arrays, the whole INFO array gets sorted together. So the overlaying arrays basically act as keys to the overlaid array. A cool feature, but unrelated to this issue of overlaying an array over a group of similar fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you code the array last, you don't have to hardcode the positions of all the other subfields.

```
dcl-ds *n;                             
    bl01 char(7);                      
    bl02 char(7);                      
    bl03 char(7);  
    ...                 
    bl char(7) dim(12) pos(1);  
end-ds;
```

You can also use SAMEPOS(bl01) to define the array starting at the same position as BL01. I like coding it this way because it makes the relationship between BL01 and BL clearer. Using SAMEPOS would be the best way to code the subfields if BL01 wasn't the first subfield in the data structure.

```
dcl-ds *n;                             
    bl01 char(7);                      
    bl02 char(7);                      
    bl03 char(7);  
    ...                 
    bl char(7) dim(12) samepos(bl01);  
end-ds;
```